# Spring boot elasticsearch @Field name not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

...

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Moore-SR6</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Elasticsearch version: 6.8

I am defining my @Document class like:

```
@Document(indexName = "test-spring", type = "_doc")
public class Domain
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(name = "domain_name", type = Text)
    private String domainName;

    ........getters and setters
}
```

The ES document gets indexed but with field domainName, I would expect to be "domain_name" as it is specified in the @Field annotation.

I have also tried @JsonProperty("domain_name") in such case the field is ignored.

is this a known issue?

thank you.

**Edit (copied pom):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-es-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-es-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <elasticsearch.version>6.8.7</elasticsearch.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Moore-SR6</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: How do you configure the connection to Elasticsearch? Do you have a custom configuration for Spring Data Elasticsearch? And is the index already created in Elasticsearch or is this autocreated?

Comment: I tried both autocreating it and creating it myself before indexing.

The configuration to elasticsearch is just:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: http://localhost:9200
      read-timeout: 10s

Comment: can you please add the relevant part of your application configuration?

Comment: this is all config I have:
```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/database
    username: username
    password: password
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: http://localhost:9200
      read-timeout: 10s
      username:
      password:

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
```

that's all I have configured. Documents get indexed but with java class attribute names not the ones define in @Field

Comment: please add the complete maven dependencies in your question (and not as comment), otherwise it's not possible to reproduce this.

Comment: I just added the full pom on another answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A little technical background: Spring Data Elasticsearch (in that version) internally uses an implementation of the interface `EntityMapper` to convert the entities into the JSON format needed for Elasticsearch and back.

The Spring Boot autoconfiguration instantiates an ElasticsearchRestTemplate which internally uses the `DefaultEntityMapper` that is just a thin wrapper around Jackson. This implementation causes many problems, one of these hit you, and that's the custom naming of properties.

So from version 3.2 on there is an alternative implementation available, the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`, but this must be explicitly configured. You will need to add a configuration class like this to your application:

```
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() //
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200") //
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public EntityMapper entityMapper() {

        ElasticsearchEntityMapper entityMapper = new ElasticsearchEntityMapper(
                elasticsearchMappingContext(), new DefaultConversionService()
        );
        entityMapper.setConversions(elasticsearchCustomConversions());

        return entityMapper;
    }
}
```

Please note, that here the Elasticsearch host is given without the *http://* prefix, you may want to add a different property to your configuration and autowire this with a `$Value` property into this configuration class.

**Note:**

From the next major version on (4.0), the old Jackson based EntityMapper will not be available anymore, and this custom configuration of the EntityMapper will not be needed.